# Centos 7.9 ssh connection failure from macbook

Tags: centos, ssh, sudo, logs, openssh

Ssh connection failure from macbook. This stopped working after trying to migrate to Centos 8

```
MacBook-Pro:~ $ ssh -Y -vvv xxxxxxx@152.3.36.72 -p 32
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 152.3.36.72 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/terry/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/terry/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 152.3.36.72 [152.3.36.72] port 32.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 152.3.36.72 port 32: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 152.3.36.72 port 32: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`152.3.36.72 port 32: Connection refused` indicates that the host `152.3.36.72` doesn't have a `ssh` server running on port 32.

As you were upgrading the system it is possible that the old `ssh` configuration with non-standard port 32 was overwritten with a new default configuration. Try connecting to the default port `22`.

Another possibility is that you have the firewall configured to block access and return ICMP port unreachable.

Comment: or firewall is in place preventing connection to that port